# Opening port for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, networking, port, iptables

I've been trying to make Postgres available over the network but so far have been unable to do so.

According to netstat, postgres is listening on the right port:

```
#netstat -anltp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2385/postgres
```

But when I try to nmap from another device, the port appears to be closed.

```
#nmap -p 5432 marvin
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-31 10:31 CET
Nmap scan report for marvin (*.*.*.*)
Host is up (0.00048s latency).
rDNS record for *.*.*.*: marvin.*.*
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql
```

My guess is, it has to do something with the fact that I'm using a hostname instead of an IP, but since the IP changes here every so often, I'd rather use the hostname.

I've already set listen_addresses = '*', which was the solution to another similar problem I've found here, but to no avail. I've also experimented with different settings in the pg_hba.conf but the port remained closed.

```
host    all     all     .jarvis         trust
host    all     all     jarvis         trust
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/24      trust
```

I've also used several examples I've found for my iptables, but no luck there either.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresqlflags: FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             Marvin               tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:postgresql state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  Marvin               anywhere             tcp spt:postgresql dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED
```

And lastly, I've tried to connect via telnet, no luck there either

```
telnet marvin 5432
Trying *.*.*.*...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refusedo connect to the port
```

Yet, there are no issues on 22.

```
telnet marvin 22
Trying *.*.*.*...
Connected to marvin.*.*.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
```

Can anyone tell me if there's a setting somewhere I misinterpreted or of its an issue with using hostnames?

Answer (score 3):

Look at your netstat output again. You are only listening on localhost (127.0.0.1). Check your config file and restart PostgreSQL.

Comment: More specifically, in postgresql.conf, change to `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: Clearly not, otherwise netstat would say "0.0.0.0:5432". So - check your config file again and restart postgres.